# Can i make a MySQL dynamic insert on php?

Tags: php, mysql, browser, insert, explode

I'm trying to insert multiple values from a string using explode on php, i mean the string contact contents a few values that i'm trying to insert on a mysql database separating its values with a "/"

This is the php code

```
<?php
$contactos=$_GET['contacts'];    
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql12.000webhost.com","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DBNAME");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Fallo la conexion con la BD: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
                $foo = false;
 $pieces = explode("/", $contactos);
               echo $pieces[0];
               $var = count($pieces);
    echo $var;     

  for ($i = 0; $i < $var; $i++) {
        echo $pieces[i];
                    list($descripcion, $valor) = explode("-", $pieces[i]);


                     $sql = "INSERT INTO contacto ( codi_usuario, descripcion, valor_contacto)
            VALUES ('mierda', '$descripcion', '$valor')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            $foo = true;
        }else
        {
            $foo = false;
        }
                 }

    if($foo){

                  echo "paso";
                  }else{

                   echo "no paso";
                  }
?>
```

Comment: You might want to edit your SQL connection string and remove the password, is it's visible publicly and presumably anyone can use it to access your database. I would also change your password after your edit.

Comment: First of all have you noticed you are using `$pieces[i]` without the dollar sign? I mean it should be `$pieces[$i]`. In 2 lines after your for loop

Comment: @sinazza Try it - it'll work. PHP assume `i` is a variable in this case. However, I am all against this... but it'll work hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> '$descripcion', '$valor'

You need to escape the strings before interpolating.  There could be an apostrophe in them.